# Java method overriding issue

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am having problem to call the setCustomer method. 
The coding are as below:

```
public class Customer {

    public int customerID = 001;
    public String name ="name required";
    public String address ="address required";
    public String email ="email required";

    public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add ){
    }

    public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add , String em){
    }

    public void displayCustomer(){

        System.out.println("Customer ID: " +customerID);
        System.out.println("Customer Name: " +name);
        System.out.println("Customer Address: " +address);
        System.out.println("Customer Email: " +email);

    }//end of display method

}//end of class


public class CustomerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Customer c1 = new Customer();
        Customer c2 = new Customer();
        c1.setCustomer(002, "ishihi", "alalalla2");
        c2.setCustomer(003, "tututu", "kikiki","rans@g.com");
        c1.displayCustomer();
        c2.displayCustomer();
    }
}
```

The output I got is:

```
Customer ID: 1
Customer Name: name required
Customer Address: address required
Customer Email: email required
Customer ID: 1
Customer Name: name required
Customer Address: address required
Customer Email: email required
```

I want to display the content i set for the c1 and c2 in the main function but it is keep showing as above.

Comment: how about setting them inside your set method

Answer (score 2):

Your `setCustomer` methods are empty

```
public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add ){
}

public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add , String em){
}
```

Implement the behavior you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add ){ }
```

This method doesn't do much, your method body is `{}` after all, so it should come as no surprise that it has no effect. Programming doesn't change the state of objects by magic -- you have to write the code to do this. Fill in the `{}` with code that **sets your object's fields**, and you'll see the magic come to life.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually set all your class fields in your methods. They are currently empty and don't do anything.

```
public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add ){
    customerID = custID;
    name = nm;
    address = add;
}

public void setCustomer(int custID, String nm , String add , String em){
    customerID = custID;
    name = nm;
    address = add;
    email = em;
}
```

And in your `main`, use those methods. You are currently not calling them:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Customer c1 = new Customer();
    c1.setCustomer(1, "name1", "address1", "email1");
    Customer c2 = new Customer();
    c1.setCustomer(2, "name2", "address2", "email2");
}
```